# Nuxt: How to load html4 with activeX in Nuxt App?

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js, activex

I want to use activeX so I will call the activeX by html

And then I will use `<object>` tag like this

`<OBJECT ID="SAMPLE_API" CLASSID="CLSID:AnGUID"  width=0 height=0></OBJECT>`

And the activeX of `CLSID:AnGUID` has some functions.

And I need to call a function of there in javascript, like
`var ticket = SAMPLE_API.GetTicket("APP_ID") // this return will be string`

Well so, I need to use html with activeX in Nuxt project

But I don't know where to insert it on `<template></template>` and its files(bulahbulah.html) on the directories. When I tried to insert the file in `~/pages`, then the webpage emitted
"ReferenceError
File is not defined."

And it happened when I made directory like `~/login`, and moved the files to the directory, too.

How can I use the html in the Nuxt project in this case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that as activeX has been deprecated for more than 7 years now.
There's no browser support for it also.

Comment: Well some banks of my country use activeX, so I need to make it run well. I will use internet explorer 11 for the test, even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this.

1. Use `res.sendFile()`. If you connect a url which is using `res.sendFile(/path/to/bulahbulah.html)`, it will show the `bulahbulah.html` page which can use activeX(But you need to use internet explorer to run the activeX basically).

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile('/path/to/bulahbulah.html')
}
```

2. When you need to use the values from the `bulahbulah.html` page in Nuxt App, then you can transport the values with query string. If the Nuxt page is `/nuxtPage` then, you can append a line in `bularbular.html` page like this

```
self.location.replace("/nuxtPage?foo=bar);
```

So, you can use the values from the normal html page. But, as it transport the values as just query string, need to watch out in using secret values.